# Ideal classes of $\mathcal{O}_k$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How can I show if two ideals are in the same ideal class when considering the ideal classes of $\mathcal{O}_k$? Could someone show me an example of discarding ideals that have been used before?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what the context is and what you want to know specifically, and do with the information? This is quite broad as asked.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the ideal class group of $\sqrt{-23}$, and calculated $\underline{p_{2}}$, $\underline{p_{2}}$', $\underline{p_{3}}$, $\underline{p_{3}}'$ and $(5)$. I'm just not sure about how to figure out the ideal classes. Would $(5)$ be in the class of $(1)$ and then we need two more classes (I know the class number is 3)? Do we consider the $\underline{p_{i}}$s? Or do I multiply our and see what I get for $(2)$, $(3)$, in which case $(3)=(3, 3\sqrt{-23})$ which is also principle right?

Comment: Using the [Minkowski bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound) you see that you need to check the factorization of only finitely many primes.

Comment: Oh that's what I did, I also factored everything out, just not sure which things to pick as representatives for the classes.

Comment: Further, if $p$ is a rational prime, then either it ramifies, $(p) = P^2$, it (totally) splits, $(p) = PQ$, or it is inert, $(p)$ prime in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Now, you know that a prime ramifies iff it divides the discriminant of $\mathcal{O}_K$, and that a prime $p$ splits in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})$ iff $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$...

Comment: Yep, I understand, so do I use the $\underline{p_{i}}$s for the classes or should I use $(2), (3), \ldots$ etc?

Comment: Actually, it might be easier to use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75762/on-the-class-group-of-an-imaginary-quadratic-number-field) related result...